# How to get checked checkbox value to another table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to get the checked checkbox value to another table?
After I select the user I want, then it will appear in the table next to it.
My current JS code looks "weird" and I don't seem to get it done.

JS:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").val();
 $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
   var user = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").text();        
   document.getElementById("user-list").innerHTML = user ;
 });  

});
```

Users list:

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <th>No</th>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr id="user-list">
 <td>1</td>
 <td>Peter</td>
 <td>1234</td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value="Peter" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>Adam</td>
 <td>643</td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value="Adam" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Selected user:

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <th>No</th>
 <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th>1</th>
 <th>Adam</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Result:

User list:

```
| No | Name | ID | Action |
|----|------|----|--------|
|1   |Peter |123 | [ ]    |
|2   |Adam  |643 | [/]    |
```

Selected user:

```
| No | Name |
|----|------|
|1   |Adam  |
```

Answer (score 1):

I give you a sample code for your reference:

```js
function addUser(vv){
    
  if (vv.checked){
    let row=$(vv).parents("tr")[0];
    let selectedUserTable=document.getElementById("selectedUser");
    let selectedUserRow=selectedUserTable.insertRow(selectedUserTable.rows.length);
    let cell=selectedUserRow.insertCell(selectedUserRow.cells.length);
    cell.textContent=row.cells[0].textContent;
    cell=selectedUserRow.insertCell(selectedUserRow.cells.length);
    cell.textContent=row.cells[1].textContent;
  }  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="user-list">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>1234</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="Peter" onchange="addUser(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>643</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="Adam" onchange="addUser(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="selectedUser">
</table>
```